# Product quantity limit on Shopify Buy Button

Tags: html, shopify, buybutton.js

Has anyone been able to find a way to set a quantity limit on Shopify buy buttons to limit how many of an item a customer can purchase? My buy button is embedded on my Squarespace website and the embedded code is listed below. I am looking for a solution that doesn't require a third party app to set up

```
 <div id='product-component-6666666666666'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
(function () {
  var scriptURL = 'https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/latest/buy-button-storefront.min.js';
  if (window.ShopifyBuy) {
    if (window.ShopifyBuy.UI) {
      ShopifyBuyInit();
    } else {
      loadScript();
    }
  } else {
    loadScript();
  }
  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = scriptURL;
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);
    script.onload = ShopifyBuyInit;
  }
  function ShopifyBuyInit() {
    var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
      domain: 'aaaaaaaaaaa.myshopify.com',
      storefrontAccessToken: '1121212121212121212121212121212',
    });
    ShopifyBuy.UI.onReady(client).then(function (ui) {
      ui.createComponent('product', {
        id: '7777777777777',
        node: document.getElementById('product-component-6666666666666'),
        moneyFormat: '%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D',
        options: {
  "product": {
    "styles": {
      "product": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "max-width": "100%",
          "margin-left": "0",
          "margin-bottom": "50px"
        },
        "text-align": "left"
      },
      "title": {
        "font-family": "Roboto, sans-serif",
        "font-size": "26px"
      },
      "button": {
        "font-family": "Roboto, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "padding-top": "15px",
        "padding-bottom": "15px",
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#464646"
        },
        "background-color": "#292929",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#464646"
        },
        "border-radius": "40px"
      },
      "quantityInput": {
        "font-size": "14px",
        "padding-top": "15px",
        "padding-bottom": "15px"
      },
      "price": {
        "font-family": "Roboto, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "font-size": "18px"
      },
      "compareAt": {
        "font-family": "Roboto, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "font-size": "15.299999999999999px"
      },
      "unitPrice": {
        "font-family": "Roboto, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "font-size": "15.299999999999999px"
      }
    },
    "layout": "horizontal",
    "contents": {
      "img": true,
      "imgWithCarousel": false,
      "description": true
    },
    "width": "100%",
    "text": {
      "button": "Add to cart"
    },
    "googleFonts": [
      "Roboto"
    ]
  },
  "productSet": {
    "styles": {
      "products": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "margin-left": "-20px"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "modalProduct": {
    "contents": {
      "img": true,
      "imgWithCarousel": false,
      "button": false,
      "buttonWithQuantity": true
    },
    "styles": {
      "product": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "max-width": "100%",
          "margin-left": "0px",
          "margin-bottom": "0px"
        }
      },
      "button": {
        "font-family": "Roboto, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "padding-top": "15px",
        "padding-bottom": "15px",
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#464646"
        },
        "background-color": "#292929",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#464646"
        },
        "border-radius": "40px"
      },
      "quantityInput": {
        "font-size": "14px",
        "padding-top": "15px",
        "padding-bottom": "15px"
      },
      "title": {
        "font-family": "Helvetica Neue, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "font-size": "26px",
        "color": "#4c4c4c"
      },
      "price": {
        "font-family": "Helvetica Neue, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "normal",
        "font-size": "18px",
        "color": "#4c4c4c"
      },
      "compareAt": {
        "font-family": "Helvetica Neue, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "normal",
        "font-size": "15.299999999999999px",
        "color": "#4c4c4c"
      },
      "unitPrice": {
        "font-family": "Helvetica Neue, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "normal",
        "font-size": "15.299999999999999px",
        "color": "#4c4c4c"
      }
    },
    "googleFonts": [
      "Roboto"
    ],
    "text": {
      "button": "Add to cart"
    }
  },
  "option": {
    "styles": {
      "label": {
        "font-family": "Roboto, sans-serif"
      },
      "select": {
        "font-family": "Roboto, sans-serif"
      }
    },
    "googleFonts": [
      "Roboto"
    ]
  },
  "cart": {
    "styles": {
      "button": {
        "font-family": "Roboto, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "padding-top": "15px",
        "padding-bottom": "15px",
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#464646"
        },
        "background-color": "#292929",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#464646"
        },
        "border-radius": "40px"
      }
    },
    "text": {
      "total": "Subtotal",
      "button": "Checkout"
    },
    "popup": false,
    "googleFonts": [
      "Roboto"
    ]
  },
  "toggle": {
    "styles": {
      "toggle": {
        "font-family": "Roboto, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "background-color": "#292929",
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#464646"
        },
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#464646"
        }
      },
      "count": {
        "font-size": "14px"
      }
    },
    "googleFonts": [
      "Roboto"
    ]
  }
},
      });
    });
  }
})();
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do. Once you play an item in checkout, the customer could navigate to the cart, and in the typical cart, the update exists to change quantity. Anyone can use a variant ID and a quantity to checkout whatever quantity they want. It is pretty hard to limit quantity in checkout. You can try, but mostly, any customer with any sense of how Shopify works will know how to change a quantity to what they want. No Apps can help with this.